# list not ordering well dynamic children

Tags: reactjs

My problem is that react is not respecting the order I am giving by the backend.

It gives me a warning.

Child objects should have non-numeric keys so ordering is preserved

I checked the documentation and I don't know where the error is.

[dynamic children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

I'm passing the key to the component and it doesn't work...

I have a Films component with this code

```
{this.props.films && this.props.films.map((film, i) =>
              <FilmsListItem key={film.ID()} data={film}/>
).toJS()}
```

Then I have the FilmListItem with this

```
<div>
          <div className="show-image">
              <img onClick={this.modifyFilm.bind(this, this.props.data)}
                   src={this.props.data.foto()}
                   title={this.props.data.nombre()}
                   alt={this.props.data.nombre()}
                   width="230"
                   height="345"/>
              <input type="button"
                     className="delete"
                     value="BORRAR"
                     onClick={this.remove.bind(this, this.props.data)}>
              </input>
              <div className="diccionarios">
                <button onClick={this.diccionarios.bind(this, this.props.data)}>PALABRAS</button>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Is `key={film.ID()}` a numeric key?

Comment: i converted it to a string and no working

Comment: `key={ 'key' + film.ID() }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of data structure does

```javascript
this.props.films && this.props.films.map((film, i) =>
  <FilmsListItem key={film.ID()} data={film}/>
).toJS()
```

return? My guess is that it returns an object, and React is forced to use the object's keys (which are probably numeric) as the keys for the children.

Consider [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/y9Ls8apf/) that demonstrates the error:

```javascript
var Test = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var children = { 1: <div>test1</div>, 2: <div>test2</div> };
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
});
```

However, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/p9fvyvs2/) uses non-numeric keys, and does not give the same warning:

```javascript
var Test = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var children = { a: <div>test1</div>, b: <div>test2</div> };
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
});
```

Neither does [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/1bu1rcnz/), that uses an array:

```javascript
var Test = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var children = [<div key={1}>test1</div>, <div key={2}>test2</div>];
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
});
```

Since the keys of objects are always strings:

```javascript
var test = { 1: true };
console.log(test["1"]); // true
```

React can't guarantee the ordering of the values of the child object:

```javascript
["1", "2", "9", "10", "11", "19", "20", "21", "30"].sort()
// ["1", "10", "11", "19", "2", "20", "21", "30", "9"]
```

Consider transforming your data into an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to covert to a  a string:

```
  <FilmsListItem key={film.ID().toString()} data={film}/>
```

Comment: i tried with film.nombre() before and no luck.I did what are you suggesting and same result