# How to get a reference to nested child in React

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

My app structure is as follows (`HighOrderComponent` is Alt's `AltContainer` wrapper):

```
<App>
    <HighOrderComponent store={someStore...}>
        <MyCanvasComponent ref="canvasRef" />
    </HighOrderComponent>
</App>
```

I need to expose a `collectData()` method from the `MyCanvasComponent` since the canvas needs to transform its content to a base64 image once a button is clicked in the `App` component.

I would like, in the `button`'s `click` handler, to be able to use `this.refs.canvasRef.collectData()`.

Unfortunately, it seems that nested components `refs` are not being taken into account. I know that generally `refs` should be considered private (i.e. belong to the `HighOrderComponent`) but -

1. They are not available on it as well, meaning if I assign a `ref="highOrderComponentRef"` then `this.refs.highOrderComponentRef` would work but `this.refs.highOrderComponentRef.refs.canvasRef` wouldn't.
2. The `HighOrderComponent` is a generic component and therefore does not know what its children would be.

The `this.props.children` on the `HighOrderComponent` are of `ReactElement` type which is lightweight and does not expose their methods.

The only solution so far is to pass the `MyCanvasComponent` a callback in which it will send itself and a reference will be saved, but this is tedious and against best practices as per [React 0.13 release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html)

> ref resolution order has changed slightly such that a ref to a component is available immediately after its componentDidMount method is called; this change should be observable only if your component calls a parent component's callback within your componentDidMount, which is an anti-pattern and should be avoided regardless

Comment: Why do need to call the `collectData()` method on the ref (which is the mounted DOM component)? Alternative (and more in line with react): define a state `collectData: false` in The <App> component, pass this to the canvas component `<MyCanvasComponent collectData={this.state.collectData}/>`. Inside the canvascomponent (probably inside getInitialData + inside componentWillUpdate), do `if (this.props.collectData) {collectData();}`. When user clicks button (part of top <App> component), this fires a `this.setState({collectData: true})`

Comment: @wintvelt willl try this. thanks

Comment: Ran into this same issue :( Unfortunately both the higher order component and the child are packages, therefore I don't feel entirely comfortable modifying them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list not ordering well dynamic children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821993/list-not-ordering-well-dynamic-children)